# 2D arrays - Asking for rows and columns

Tags: java

Hello I seem to be having an error. The code is supposed to ask the user the number of rows and columns. Next, it will ask to enter fruits then list it. Here is the code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ");
int rows = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter number of columns: ");
int columns = input.nextInt();
String[][] array = new String[rows][columns];
System.out.println("Enter fruits:");
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
            array[i][j] = input.nextLine();
        }
      System.out.println();
    }

   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
      System.out.print(array[i][j]+"\t");
     }
    System.out.println();
   }
```

The problem it asks for one less String input. For example:
Enter number of rows: 2
Enter number of columns: 2
Enter fruits:
apple
banana
orange
Then it prints the fruits. It should have allowed four fruits to be inputted, since rows x columns, which is 2x2 = 4, but it only asked for three inputs. What did I do wrong?

Comment: nextint .... dont read the end of the line

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ, Thank you, I understand what was the problem now. Do I have to delete this question now?

Comment: you can keep this question, if you think other might have a similar problem. You can best answer your question and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++)
```